# How to hide elements (with smooth transition) by class with javascript?

Tags: javascript, css-transitions, fadeout

I have a group of divs that share the same **class** (*optionsclass*). The display is set to **block**. When a user clicks them the following javascript function is executed the display is changed to **none**.

```
function hideBlockElementsByClass(className)
{
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    for(i in elements)
    {
        elements[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

The transition between display block and none is quite rough and I would like to make a smoother transition. What's the best strategy to accomplish this?

Comment: You could try transitioning the `opacity` property rather than `display` (and obviously change the JS accordingly too).

Comment: Have you consider jQuery?

Comment: $('#elements[i].id').fadeOut('slow');

Comment: People are forgetting how Javascript works, with all these simple Jquery solutions. In my opinion learn Javascript first before JQuery, so let's give him a javascript answer he asks ofr ;)

Comment: You could add a class and use CSS3 transition on the list items.. then your animation can be achieved different ways (opacity, height..), the problem with jquery transition is they are not smooth outside of desktop browsers

Comment: Use CSS3 : http://bavotasan.com/2011/a-simple-fade-with-css3/

Comment: I need pure javascript/css solution for now. With jQuery is just  $(".optionsclass").fadeOut(1000);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644673/hide-all-elements-with-class-using-plain-javascript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use CSS3 :

```
.className { 
 opacity: 0; 
 visibility: hidden;
 -webkit-transition: visibility 0.2s linear,
 opacity 0.2s linear;
 -moz-transition: visibility 0.2s linear,
 opacity 0.2s linear;
 -o-transition: visibility 0.2s linear,
 opacity 0.2s linear; 
}

.className:hover { 
visibility: visible; 
opacity: 1; 
}
```

Comment: Simple yet effective! Thanks. Just needed to replace elements[i].style.display = "none"; to elements[i].className += " className"; and add the class to the css and works fine.

Answer (score 1):

While Sridhar gives a nice CSS3 solution and other mention Jquery.

Here you can find a pure javascript/CSS solution:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/7315/fade-in-and-fade-out-in-pure-javascript

Comment: For pure javascript the link you gave its great.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

**HTML**

```
<div class = "image"  onclick = "eff()"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .transition {
        -moz-transition: 2s width;
        width: 150px;
        height: 100px;

    }
```

**Script**

```
function eff() {
    var k = document.getElementsByClassName("image"); 
    k[0].className = "transition";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in plain javascript:(Will work on IE10, chrome, firefox, safari, android, ios)

```
<script>
       function hideBlockElementsByClass(className) {
            var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
            console.log(elements.length)
            for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                (function (a) {
                    elements[a].addEventListener('webkitTransitionEnd', function () {
                        elements[a].style.display = "none";
                    }, false);
                    elements[a].addEventListener('mozTransitionEnd', function () {
                        elements[a].style.display = "none";
                    }, false);
                    elements[a].addEventListener('oTransitionEnd', function () {
                        elements[a].style.display = "none";
                    }, false);
                    elements[a].addEventListener('transitionend', function () {
                        elements[a].style.display = "none";
                    }, false);
                })(i);
                elements[i].style.webkitTransitionDuration = "1s";
                elements[i].style.mozTransitionDuration = "1s";
                elements[i].style.oTransitionDuration = "1s";
                elements[i].style.transitionDuration = "1s";
                elements[i].style.opacity = "0";
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `CSS` transitioning with your Javascript events:

```js
const block=document.querySelector('.block');

block.addEventListener('click',function(){
this.classList.add('hidden');
})
```

```css
.container{
  position:retlative
}
.block{
  transition: visibility 0.2s linear,opacity 0.3s linear;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.hidden{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility:hidden;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class='container'>
        <div class='block' title='click me'>
        click me
        </div>
      </div>
   </body> 
</html>
```